# Delete comment not published by app using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a simple app using the Facebook Graph API where I can retrieve the comments on a post and delete those comments. I have the following permissions set up: user_posts and publish_actions.

When I try to delete a Facebook comment on one of my posts using my app, I get the following error: "Users can only delete their own comments published by the same app." Is there a way around this? My app can successfully delete the comments that originate from my app, but I want to delete comments that were not posted by my app.

Thanks

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: There is no way to do it at all? Like Facebook does not allow it, correct?

Comment: It is not possible in the API.